# PHP shell for Mac echo value on the same line

Tags: php, terminal

I'm using the default PHP shell that comes with my Mac.

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell
php > echo 5-2;
3php >
```

My problem is when I echo-ed the value, it didn't come in a separate line. Any fix? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want a newline, you have to echo it explicitly:

```
php> echo 5-2, PHP_EOL;
```

or:

```
php> echo 5-2, "\n";
```

To see an array, use `print_r` or `var_dump`:

```
php> var_dump($i);
```

Comment: is there any way to set it echo PHP_EOL automatically?

Comment: I don't think so. It just does what it would do when executing that line in an ordinary PHP script.

Comment: is there any short way to echo the value to a new line? I tried \n, it printed the value in a new line with a warning "Fatal error: Undefined constant 'n' in php shell code on line 1", same with \r.

Comment: It should be `"\n"` in quotes.